# Default object attribute not defaulting for HTML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, attributes, radio-button

```
if @challenge.name == 'foo'
  @challenge.category = 'habit'
  @challenge.days_challenged = 21
  @challenge.why = 'bar'
else
```

`:days_challenged` & `:why` are properly being set in the _form for `foo` but not `:category`.

```
  <div class="challenge-category">
    <input class="date-format-switcher" type="radio" value="goal" name="challenge[category]" id="challenge_category_goal">
    <label for="challenge_category_goal">Goal</label>

    <input class="date-format-switcher" type="radio" value="habit" name="challenge[category]" id="challenge_category_habit">
    <label for="challenge_category_habit">Habit</label>
  </div>
  <%= f.number_field :days_challenged, class: 'day-challenge' %>
  <%= f.text_area :why %>
```

Comment: please, show your controller method and view full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are purposefully custom-coding your radio buttons.  The selected radio button should have the attribute "checked", i.e.

```
<input class="date-format-switcher" type="radio" value="habit" 
  name="challenge[category]" id="challenge_category_habit" checked />
```

To set dynamically:

```
<%= f.radio_button :category, 'goal', class: 'date-format-switcher' %>
<%= f.radio_button :category, 'habit', class: 'date-format-switcher' %>
```

Comment: That makes it always default to "habit". Sometimes the featured challenges are a "goal", which means that needs to be checked

Comment: I know.  You need to programmatically set it to checked if the value of the radio button matches `@challenge.category`.  Rails has a helper `f.radio_button` that will do this just like the other form fields.

Comment: See edit above. That will basically yield the same HTML, but let's Rails handle the form building for you.